# Rails Routing (root :to => ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I know how to set the routes root of my rails app to a controller and an action.

But how to add an id?

`/pages/show/1` should be the root.

How do I set this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Had this same problem and this worked for me:

```
root :to => "pages#show", :id => '1'
```

Comment: This is good except that root_path() is now adding `?id=1` to the url when linked from elsewhere in the app...

Comment: @MatthewD - curious why would you want the root route to point to an id of one?

Answer (score 32):

As of [Rails 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root), you can declare the root route like this:

```
root 'controller#action'
```

Comment: But how do you incorporate the :id into the route?

Comment: @dlu We can pass extra parameters.
`root 'controller#action', {your_params}`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Rails 5.1 to point the home page to a specific blog.  In config/routes.rb I have ...

```
root 'blogs#show', {id: 1}
```

This will point the root route to /blogs/1

I'm doing this on a blog site I'm building.  The first blog will be the main site blog as well as the homepage.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Matthew's solution works, but I think it is more readable to fetch the object.  For example, let's say you want to root to the `Page#show` action for the page with the name "landing".  This is a bit more readable:

```
root :to => "pages#show", :id => Page.find_by_name("landing").id
```

From a performance perspective, this solution is worse because it requires an additional database query, but this solution is more readable if performance is not a high priority.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 match 'pages/show/:id' => 'pages#show', :as => :root
```

In Rails console. `rake routes | grep root`, should show something like:

```
root     /pages/show/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"show"}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use Rails 5.1
Add this to the config/routes.rb

```
root 'pages#show', {id: 1}
```